# The method '[]=' was called on null. When Creating List of Map

Tags: list, flutter, dart, maps

I want to create a list of the map but when I was adding a map to the list I got this error, The method '[]=' was called on null.

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> a = [];
```

**Function to Fill List with a Map.**

```
void populateLists()
  {
    Map<String,dynamic> tempData;
      tempData["CompanyName"] ="Hello";
      tempData["PricePerQuantity"] = "Yo";
      a.add(tempData);
      print(a);
      tempData.clear();
  }
```

Can you please tell me what steps I should take to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Map<String,dynamic> tempData` is `null` inside `populateLists()` method

Use this

```
void populateLists()
  {
      Map<String,dynamic> tempData= Map<String,dynamic>();
      tempData["CompanyName"] ="Hello";
      tempData["PricePerQuantity"] = "Yo";
      a.add(tempData);
      print(a);
      tempData.clear();
  }
```

instead of this

```
 void populateLists()
  {
      Map<String,dynamic> tempData;
      tempData["CompanyName"] ="Hello";
      tempData["PricePerQuantity"] = "Yo";
      a.add(tempData);
      print(a);
      tempData.clear();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, List "a" is still empty after even adding tempData Map.

Comment: @Creator try to intialise your list `a` like this `List<Map<String, dynamic>> a = List<Map<String, dynamic>>();`

Comment: Problem Is, I was clearing tempData. After removing that statement program is working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your `tempData` with `Map<String,dynamic>()`, Right now `tempData` is `null`.

```dart
Map<String,dynamic> tempData= Map<String,dynamic>();
```